# C++ Direct X sprite class, problems with vector

Tags: c++, directx, sprite, vector

So I've created a sprite class using LPD3DXSPRITE to hold a sprite.  It works fantastic, until I use it in a vector.  The issue arises when the vector creates a copy and destroys the other sprite.  When it does so it calls the destructor, which calls for the release of the LPD3DXSPRITE object.  When this object is destroyed, the copy can no longer call it and I get a memory error.

How do I get around this?  I was thinking about a solution that involved having copies point to originals and then the pointer would go null if there was nothing to point to, indicating that the destructor should kill the sprite, but that seemed a bit crazy.

I've included some of the code below.  Also please note that I'm still learning C++ (I'm a C# programmer by profession) so if you see anything crazy please let me know without going off on me.

Sprite.h

```
#ifndef SPRITE_H
#define SPRITE_H

#include <d3dx9.h>

// 
class Sprite
    {
    private:
        LPD3DXSPRITE sprite;
```

Sprite.cpp

```
#include "sprite.h"

// Copy constructor
Sprite::Sprite(Sprite &_copy)
{
    center = _copy.center;
    color = _copy.color;
    matrix = _copy.matrix;
    position = _copy.position;
    rotation = _copy.rotation;
    scale = _copy.scale;
    sourceRect = _copy.sourceRect;
    sprite = _copy.sprite;
    texture = _copy.texture;
}

// Full constructor which fully initializes the sprite.
Sprite::Sprite(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 _device, LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 _texture)
{
    Initialize(_device,_texture);
}

Sprite::~Sprite()
{
    sprite->Release();
}

// Initializes values and creates the sprite
void Sprite::Initialize(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 _device, LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 _texture)
{
    Initialize();

    // Set our variables
    texture = _texture;

    // If we don't succeed throw an error so we know things
    // got ****ed up somehow
    if (!SUCCEEDED(D3DXCreateSprite(_device, &sprite)))
    {
        throw("Sprite creation failed");
    }
    SetCenter();
    SetSourceRect();
}

// Sets initial values for the sprite
void Sprite::Initialize()
{
    // Sets variable to default  
}
```

Here is where I call it.

```
Testground.h

#ifndef TESTGROUND_H
#define TESTGROUND_H
#include "Console.h"
#include "Log.h"
#include "sprite.h"
#include <string>
#include "Animation.h"
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class TestGround
{
private:
    std::vector<Sprite> sprites;
```

And here's a bit of Testground.cpp

Testground.cpp

```
#include "TestGround.h"


    TestGround::TestGround(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 _device)
    {

        sprites.emplace_back(_device, tBank["TestTexture"]);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove all the code that's not related to the problem. This isn't the place for a code review :)

Comment: I'll narrow it down, it's just that last time I got yelled at for not having real code, so I'm not sure what the proper procedure is around here.  Seems I just can't be right is what the proper procedure is.

Comment: Just have the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the issue. You can assume we know you have your inlcudes and the like correct, since the code compiles.

Comment: Oh.  I never thought of it like that, figured this would be game programming not just concepts.  If I don't get an answer by tonight I'll switch the post over.  Thank you.

Comment: you didn't paste the key codes, where did you create the copy? where did you destroy the other object? paste the code where the problem occurs.

Comment: The problem occured in TestGround.h at sprites.emplace_back.  When I added a sprite object to the sprite array the array would make a copy of the object.  It would then destroy one (the original?) which would call the destructor.  That would then release the DirectX Sprite object (which is shared between the original and copy of my sprite object) causing the existing copy of my sprite object to call an empty reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:  My original answer was in terms of C++ language stuff and copying.  Now I see that the underlying object is a COM object, so there are more ways to address it.

The issue is that your Sprite class holds a raw pointer to the Direct3D sprite, which is a COM object.  If an instance of a Sprite is copied, there are now two objects with a pointer to the same COM object.  If one of the Sprites is destroyed, it destroys the COM object, the remaining Sprite left with a dangling pointer.

This copying can happen when the vector needs to grow.  The vector allocates space and copies (or moves) the objects to the new space, and the destroys the original copies.  (Moving is a C++11 feature, and it would also take some work on your part to support it.)

COM objects are reference counted, so they shouldn't be destroyed until the last release.  But the reference counting burden falls on you.  When the Sprite is copied, the reference count in the corresponding D3DXSprite object needs to be incremented.

Option 1:  You can do this directly by implementing the Sprite copy constructor and having it call AddRef on the pointer.

```
Sprite::Sprite(const Sprite &_copy) :
  center(_copy.center),
  color(_copy.color),
  // blah blah blah
  sprite(_copy.sprite)
{
  sprite->AddRef();
}
```

Option 2:  Use a smart pointer to manage the reference counts.  I find the `ATL::CComPtr` from `<atlbase.h>` to work quite well for this.

```
#include <atlbase.h>

class Sprite {
   // blah blah blah
   private:
     ATL::CComPtr<ID3DXSprite> sprite;
};
```

Now you don't even have to implement the copy constructor.  The compiler will do it for you by making one that copies each member.  When a CComPtr is copied, it increments the reference count for you.  And when your Sprite is destroyed, the CComPtr will decrement the reference count (thus you no longer need your ~Sprite destructor--or, if you do, it no longer should call sprite->Release()).

My original answer is below, and these are also valid options.

Option 1.  If you're using C++11, implement the move constructor and move assignment operator for Sprite and then put the Sprites directly into a std::vector as you're doing now.

Option 2.  Make your Sprite non-copyable (either by declaring the copy constructor and assignment operator with `= delete` or by declaring them private and not implementing them).  Then make your vector hold smart pointers to your Sprites (e.g., `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Sprite>>`).

Option 3.  Make your Sprite copy constructor and copy assignment operator do a deep copy--that is, create a new `LPD3DXSPRITE` that's set up the same way as the one in the source object.  With this approach, you can put them directly into a std::vector.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been stuck on this for a month or two now.  I'll implement this once I get back home.